# reduce dataframe to get equal amounts of rows per value (by group)

Tags: r

Suppose I have following dataset:

```
id <- c("vp01","vp01","vp01","vp01", "vp02", "vp02","vp02","vp02","vp02", "vp02")
rating <- c("0","1","0","0","1","0","1", "0", "0", "0")
Au1 <- c("150.0","100.45","80.23","133.21","94.33","102.22", "83.45", "122.65", "115.41", "109.34")

df <- data.frame(id,rating,Au1)


     id rating    Au1
1  vp01      0  150.0
2  vp01      1 100.45
3  vp01      0  80.23
4  vp01      0 133.21
5  vp02      1  94.33
6  vp02      0 102.22
7  vp02      1  83.45
8  vp02      0 122.65
9  vp02      0 115.41
10 vp02      0 109.34
```

In my dataset, there are many more 0 than 1. I would like to remove the rows in a way that within each id the number of 0 ratings matches the number of 1 ratings. The number of rows per id can differ. The result could look like this.

```
     id rating    Au1
1  vp01      0  150.0
2  vp01      1 100.45
5  vp02      1  94.33
6  vp02      0 102.22
7  vp02      1  83.45
8  vp02      0 122.65
```

I have absolutely no idea how to tackle the problem, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a count column for each `id` and `rating`, then for each `id` select the count value which is minimum and for each `id` and `rating` select that minimum number of rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_count(id, rating) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = min(n)) %>%
  group_by(rating, .add = TRUE) %>%
  #In old dplyr add = TRUE
  #group_by(rating, add = TRUE) %>%
  sample_n(n) %>%
  select(-n)


#  id    rating Au1   
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#1 vp01  0      133.21
#2 vp01  1      100.45
#3 vp02  0      102.22
#4 vp02  0      115.41
#5 vp02  1      83.45 
#6 vp02  1      94.33
```

I am using `sample_n` here to select any random `n` rows for `id` and `rating`. This can be changed if you have any preferences. For example, we can select first `n` rows, last `n` rows, or rows based on value of `Au1` column.

Comment: I know `dplyr` and similar are widely used, but I think it's useful to include a `library` or `require` function call when used. Especially with new users who may not have been exposed to it before.

Comment: I do include it in the answers usually. Forgot in this one. Updated the answer to include that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Create a grouping vector to split on in order to remove duplicates:
# group => character vector
df$group <- paste0(df$id, unlist(sapply(split(df, df$id), function(y){
        cumsum(c(TRUE, abs(diff(as.numeric(y$rating)))))
      }
    )
  )
)

# Remove data duplicated within groups: data.frame => stdout (console)
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x){
        x[!duplicated(x$group), c("id", "rating", "Au1")]
      }
    )
  ),
row.names = NULL)
```

Output:

```
#    id rating    Au1
#1 vp01      0  150.0
#2 vp01      1 100.45
#3 vp01      0  80.23
#4 vp02      1  94.33
#5 vp02      0 102.22
#6 vp02      1  83.45
#7 vp02      0 122.65
```